# Only get interface fields of kotlin-object

Tags: kotlin

I want to reduce an object down to its basic fields (comming from an interface):

```kotlin
override fun findBasicById(deliveryAddressId: Long): BasicDeliveryAddress? {
    val basicDeliveryAddress = findById(deliveryAddressId) as BasicDeliveryAddress? // returns a DeliveryAddress object
    return basicDeliveryAddress // Here I still get the full DeliveryAddress!
}
```

However, `basicDeliveryAddress` still contains all fields from the class which implements the interface. How can I get rid of all fields, not declared in the interface (in this case the users-object)?

```kotlin
interface BasicDeliveryAddress {
    var street: String
    // some other fields
}
```

```kotlin
data class DeliveryAddress (
        override var name: String,
        // override all other fields
) : BasicDeliveryAddress {
    var user: User? = null
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know anything about SpringBoot, so I don't know if this resolves the root problem, but you can use an anonymous implementation that wraps it as a delegate to obscure the extra fields.

```
fun BasicDeliveryAddress.toBasic() = object: BasicDeliveryAddress by this {}
```

Comment: This exactly what i need. Anyways, can I also do this within the object without an extension-function?

Comment: Yes, you would put `fun toBasic() = object: BasicDeliveryAddress by this {}` inside `DeliveryAddress`. You could alternatively put it in `BasicDeliveryAddress` directly, but then it will implicitly be an `open` function because interface functions are always open.

Comment: Maybe you can also add that to your comment - Solved my problem, thanks.